# Screen capture using dotNetBrowser?

Tags: c#, dotnetbrowser

I'm new for DotNetBrowser, are there any way to capture desktop using Dotnetbrwser?

I want to share screen through the webrtc.

Comment: Does https://dotnetbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/discussions/topics/9000033514 help?

Comment: Yes,  there is a way to capture the desktop.

Comment: @nicomp Do you have any Idea about that? I could not find anything about it? How it is doing?

Comment: @Suravi I found it in about 1000 milliseconds with The Google. :)

Comment: Do you mean screen sharing like https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/Pluginfree-Screen-Sharing/#904117550779 ?